Possible to run batch job to export Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations Data Management Export Project to a Sharepoint Folder?
I'm wondering if it is possible to have a batch job to auto export Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations Data Management Export Project to a Sharepoint Folder? Thank you.
